# Euicc Manager Android get response after euiccManager.downloadSubscription

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, e-sim

Hi I followed the https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/esim-euicc-api guidelines to make a carrier app, the euiccManager.downloadSubscription(...) is called with a callback intent that has a boardcast receiver. The problem is that the onReceive method is never triggered not the onNewIntent from the activity.
Do you know how to get the progress or status from e-sim downlaodSubscription ?

Comment: Do you confirm your device has LPA app?

Comment: @Prabhakaran how do I know that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the LPA permission during the `BroadcastReceiver` registration, it will work.

Comment: I'll try but generally I need a special certificate(to sign the build) for that(downloading) right ? it's not going to work in debug mode, right ?
 Also do you know how can I get an e-sim string for testing? is the one from documentation working ?

Comment: there are test profiles:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/esim-test-profiles

Comment: @Peter should it supposed to work with test profile without special signing of the app?